# AnsibleVaultError: Decryption failed (no vault secrets were found that could decrypt)

Tags: python, ansible

I bumped into a weird issue.

Trying to decode a vault encrypted yaml file with python library I get this error:

AnsibleVaultError: Decryption failed (no vault secrets were found that could decrypt)

Here is my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from ansible.constants import DEFAULT_VAULT_ID_MATCH
from ansible.parsing.vault import VaultLib, VaultSecret

vault = VaultLib([(DEFAULT_VAULT_ID_MATCH, VaultSecret('toto'.encode()))])
print(vault.decrypt(open('toto.yml').read()))
```

toto.yml is

```
$ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
32353335396261646339343466646261306239633333366365663862353062653632653633656162
6464663731366136633131646531303063366332633734370a653464373830666666343930393564
39393162396564356336336339666666383432323738376566626434393461376334656664396339
6461363530383238340a376333306631383762323134303931393938653837633263386664633830
61383664303562386131306234333238396434316636343230633231386138613264383566363432
6165626266626437653735383835663564313162633265643964
```

And has been generated by this command:

```
echo -n "toto" > password
ansible-vault encrypt toto.yml --vault-password-file password
```

Executing the code returns the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/adm_user/selenium-test/./vault-stuff.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(vault.decrypt(open('toto.yml').read()))
  File "/home/adm_user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ansible/parsing/vault/__init__.py", line 644, in decrypt
    plaintext, vault_id, vault_secret = self.decrypt_and_get_vault_id(vaulttext, filename=filename, obj=obj)
  File "/home/adm_user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ansible/parsing/vault/__init__.py", line 751, in decrypt_and_get_vault_id
    raise AnsibleVaultError(msg)
ansible.parsing.vault.AnsibleVaultError: Decryption failed (no vault secrets were found that could decrypt)
```

I took this example from here : [How to view/decrypt Ansible vault credentials files from within a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44142208/how-to-view-decrypt-ansible-vault-credentials-files-from-within-a-python-script)

I really don't get it..

Thanks for any help..

EDIT : Add my versions:
Tried and failed on

- Python 3.10.12 / Ansible 9.1.0 / core 2.16.2
- Python 3.9.2 / Ansible base 2.10.8

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem. You can see my test [here](https://asciinema.org/a/W1e1TsUEMhiEjhhxuaUr4Lrjb).

Comment: I can't reproduce either and I even used your vault data as is. See [here](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/b389d7ea779eb2d7804094f27389e38e)

Comment: It must be something with versions.. 
My ansible is 2.10.8
Python is  : 3.9.2


I also tried on another linux box 
with : 
ansible core 2.16.2
python 3.10.12

Comment: Thank you.. I have (finally) found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have found what caused my problem, in my ansible.cfg:

```
...
[defaults]
vault_id_match = True
...
```

This parameter seems to force you to specify a vault_id. Answer documentation found [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-vault-id-match).